# Atomic sparse-matrix-multiply-and-compare to avoid out-of-memory error

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, octave, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two sparse matrices A (logical, 80274 x 80274) and B (non-negative integer, 21018 x 80274) and a vector c (positive integer, 21018 x 1).

I'd like to find the result res (logical, 21018 x 80274) of

```
mat = B * A;
res = mat > sparse(diag(c - 1)) * spones(mat);

# Note that since c is positive, this is equivalent to
# res = bsxfun(@gt, mat, c-1)
# but octave's sparse bsxfun support is somewhat shoddy,
# so I'm doing this instead as a workaround
```

The problem is B * A has enough nonzero values (I think 60824321 which doesn't seem like a lot, but somehow, the computation of spones(mat) uses up over a gigabyte of memory before octave crashes) to exhaust all my machine's memory even though most of these do not exceed c-1.

**Is there a way to do this without computing the intermediate matrix mat = B * A ?**

CLARIFICATION: It probably doesn't matter, but B and c are actually double matrices that happen to only be holding integer values (and B is sparse).

Comment: What is `spdiag`? I can only find `spdiags` in the doc, and still it doesn't seem to make much sense to apply it to a vector?

Comment: Sorry, spdiag is a deprecated function.  It's equivalent to sparse(diag(x)), but I prefer it because it doesn't try to create a full matrix when x is a logical vector.  It's not relevant for this problem, so I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just work on the nonzero values of `mat`? (for the zero values you know the result will be 0):

```
c = c(:); % make c a column
ind = find(mat>0); % linear index
[row, ~] = ind2sub(size(mat),ind); % row index within mat (for use in c)
res = mat(ind) > c(row)-1; % results for the nonzero values of mat
```

Comment: I can, but that doesn't fix the problem.  The problem is that mat has too many nonzero values to fit in memory.  I want to bypass the part where I compute mat or at least do it in chunks.

Comment: Then you probably need a loop (over `n`, say) to compute each row of `mat` as `B(n,1)*A` and then compare that with `c(n)-1`. Or you can work in batches of as many rows as your memory can manage: `bsxfun(@gt, B(1:1000,1)*A, c(1:1000)-1)`, then `bsxfun(@gt, B(1001:2000,1)*A, c(1001:2000)-1)`, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update to Octave 3.8.1, bsxfun has been updated to be sparse aware, this greatly enhances the performances!